# PHP: Minimum value in 2D array

Tags: php

I have a 2D array in the format:

```
[
[1, 23, 20],
[2, 45, 30],
[4, 63, 40],
...
]
```

I am trying to search the array and return elements [0] and [1] from the row where element [1] is lowest. I have the following code to return the lowest value in [1] but I'm not sure how to get element [0] as well.

```
$min = PHP_INT_MAX;
foreach ($test as $i) {
    $min = min($min, $i[1]);
}
```

In the above example I would return [1, 23]

Thanks,

Comment: in general, please indicate if php4 or php5 is being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for this:

```
usort($test, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[1] - $b[1];
});

$min = $test[0];
```

Note that this uses anonymous functions, which were introduced in PHP 5.3. In previous versions, you need to use named functions and pass the name as a string to `usort`.

Comment: Who cares? It ought to still take linear time.

Comment: @erisco @lonesomeday: Sorting in PHP uses QuickSort which is `O(n^2)` which is not linear...  So it will take `n` times as many operations as a simple loop / reduce call.  Not an issue for small arrays, but potentially huge for large ones (especially due to the callbacks)...

Comment: @ircmaxell quicksort is O(nlogn) average which could be faster or equal to linear time. worst case is o(n^2).

Comment: Ah, I just realized it was a sort. Okay, same comment, but "It ought to still take nlogn time!"

Comment: @Casey: correct me if I'm wrong, but how can a sort ever take less than `O(n)` time since you still need to visit each and every node at least once (otherwise how does it do the sort).  So while `O(n log n)` will be faster than `O(n)` for small values of `n` (less than 10), quicksort won't be since it still needs to visit each `n` at least once...

Comment: @ircmaxell If every sort had to visit each value, why would we make complex sorting algorithms?  The reason quick sort can operate at O(nlogn) is that it pivots and inspects multiple smaller sublists in a single iteration.  This also makes it possible for quicksort to operate in greater than constant time.  A case when quicksort will operate in O(n^2) would be if the list is already sorted.  The number of elements in a list doesn't have bearing on the big O of quicksort, rather it is the randomness of the data.  In fact, quicksort performs better on sets whose order is more random than not.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`array_reduce`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$array = array(
    array(1, 23, 20),
    array(2, 45, 63),
    array(4, 63, 40),
);
$callback = function ($a1, $a2) {
    if ($a1[1] >= $a2[1]) {
        return $a2;
    } else {
        return $a1;
    }
}
$min = array_reduce($array, $callback, array(0, PHP_INT_MAX, 0));
var_dump($min); // array(1, 23, 20);
```

Now, this will likely have issues if you have multiple elements with identical `[1]` elements...  But it transparently handles the case where the array is empty.  And in general, all you need to do is do your comparison in the callback function for all "filtering" type problems where you can abstract the filtering to a comparison of 2 elements.  So you do string comparison, etc to determine which of the 2 is *better*...

And it should be more efficient than a sort, since it only requires a single pass over the array (It's `O(n)` whereas [sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is `O(n log n)` and at worst `O(n^2)`)...

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job.

```
$min0 = PHP_INT_MAX;
$min1 = PHP_INT_MAX;
foreach ($test as $i) {
    if($i[1] < $min1)
    {
        $min0 = $i[0];
        $min1 = $i[1];
    }
}
```

This will result in $min0 == 1 and $min1 == 23

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to introduce some basic logic:

```
$result = array(0, PHP_INT_MAX);
foreach($test as $i)
   if($i < $result[1])
      $result = array($i[0], $i[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple min (O(n)) loop like you did, and [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to assign the first two indexes when a lowest is found :

```
$min = PHP_INT_MAX;
$arrMin = array();
foreach ($test as $i) {
    if ($i[1] < $min) {
       $min = $i[1];
       $arrMin = array_slice($i, 0, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should just grab the array key of the smallest number:

```
$min = PHP_INT_MAX;
$minkey = 0;
foreach ($test as $key => $i) {
    if($min > $i[1]) {
        $min = $i[1];
        $minkey = $key;
    }
}
```

then, you can just access the whole thing with $test[$minkey]